# Application of the mean value inequality

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable map in $U$, where $U$ is convex and open, such that $Df(x)$ is injective for all $x \in U$ and 
$$\langle Df(x)(x-y), Df(y)(x-y) \rangle >0$$ if $x\neq y$.

Show that $f$ is injective.

Comment: What do you mean by the *mean value inequality*?

Comment: https://orion.math.iastate.edu/alex/415/MeanValueTheorem.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how one can prove the injectivity of $f$ by means of the mean value inequality as stated in the hyperlink.  My approach would be the following.

Fix $x \ne y$, and put $h = y - x$.  Consider the $C^1$ function $\varphi \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\varphi(t) = \langle f(x + t h) - f(x), Df(x) h \rangle.
$$
Its derivative equals
$$
\varphi'(t) = \langle Df(x + t h) h, Df(x) h \rangle.
$$
We have $\varphi(0) = 0$ and $\varphi'(0) = \langle Df(x) h, Df(x) h \rangle > 0$ (since $Df(x)$ is injective).

We claim that $\varphi'(t) > 0$ for any $t \in (0, 1]$.  Indeed, we have $\langle Df(x + t h) h, Df(x) h \rangle > 0$ if and only if $\langle Df(x + t h) (t h), Df(x) (t h) \rangle > 0$, and the last inequality is just the assumption with $y$ replaced by $x + t h$.

Consequently, $\varphi$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$, hence $\varphi(1) > 0$, from which it follows that $f(y) \ne f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much